# LinkButton.Click event not firing when dynamically attached in GridView row databound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `asp:GridView` inside of an `asp:UpdatePanel`, which has a column of `asp:LinkButton` controls.

On the row databound event, the LinkButton gets it's click event handler assigned.

I've tried every way I could find to wire up the click even and none of the events ever fire.

Am I doing something wrong?

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="test" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvClientsArchive" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="dsClients" 
            OnRowDataBound="gvClientsArchive_RowDataBound" SkinID="gvList"
            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25" Visible="false">
        ...
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gvClientsArchive_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    int company_id = int.Parse(drvRow["company_id"].ToString());
    LinkButton lnkRestore = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkRestore");
    lnkRestore.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.doRestore);
```

Button handler code:

```
private void doRestore(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTest.Text = "restore clicked";
}
```

I've also tried:

```
protected void gvClientsArchive_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    LinkButton lnkRestore = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkRestore");
    lnkRestore.Click += delegate
    {
        lblTest.Text = "restore clicked";
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowDataBound` is inappropriate if you want to register event handlers. Use `RowCreated`:

```
protected void gvClientsArchive_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType ==  DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRestore = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkRestore");
        lnkRestore.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.doRestore);
    }
}
```

`RowDataBound` is triggered only if you Databind the grid not on every postback which is needed since all controls are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. It's also too late.

If you use `TemplateFields` it's easier to register the handler declaratively on the aspx.

Comment: I will try implementing that right now. Why is it inappropriate?

Comment: Tim I am using a `TemplateField` as the column for this `LinkButton` row. I can see how to add the OnClick in the aspx, but how would I get the context for the rest of the data row, in the click handler event?

Comment: @JamesWierzba: you have to cast the `Sender` to `LinkButton`(or `Control`) and then the `NamingContainer` to `GridViewRow`. Now you can use `row.FindControl` to find all other controls in this row.

Comment: You save me after googling 1 day